# sorting gridview c# nothing happens

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I know there's a lot of posts on this topic, but none of them seems to help on my issue.

I'm trying to sort my gridview when clicking on the header titles.
i've found some solutions by searching here and other sites. but it doesn't seem to do the trick.
I hope someone can tell me if i'm missing something or what the issue could be, cause when nothing happens, i really can't tell what the issue is.

My gridview:

```
       <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting" runat="server" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#ffffff" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="black"
RowStyle-BackColor="#F2EFDF" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="White" AlternatingRowStyle-ForeColor="#000"
AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellPadding="5">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Filename" HeaderText="Filnavn">
        <ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Time" HeaderText="Uploadet"/>
    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign = "Center">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" runat="server" Text="Download" OnClick="DownloadFile"
                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

the code behind:

```
        public string SortingExpression
{
    get
    {
        if (this.ViewState["SortExpression"] == null)
            return "";
        else
            return (string)this.ViewState["SortExpression"];
    }

    set
    {
        this.ViewState["SortExpression"] = value;
    }
}

protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable m_DataTable = GridView1.DataSource as DataTable;

    if (m_DataTable != null)
    {
        DataView m_DataView = new DataView(m_DataTable);
        SortingExpression = e.SortExpression + " " + (SortingExpression.Contains("ASC") ? "DESC" : "ASC");
        m_DataView.Sort = SortingExpression;

        GridView1.DataSource = m_DataView;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

The gridview data comes from a datatable.
Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: did you check the sorting expression?

Answer (score 1):

Add SorteEpression="ColumnName" in your bound fields.

```
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Filename" HeaderText="Filnavn" SortExpression="Filename">
    <ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
</asp:BoundField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Time" HeaderText="Uploadet" SortExpression="Time"/>
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign = "Center">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" runat="server" Text="Download" OnClick="DownloadFile"
            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: It made the headers "clickable" - one step closer!
A postback is now triggered when clicking, but still nothing happens

Comment: Check this, http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/268107/Sorting-a-GridView-bound-to-a-DataTable

Comment: I solved it! the issue were in the datasource for the datatable.

Answer (score 0):

The issue were in the datatable which is created when sorting:

```
      protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e){
DataTable m_DataTable = GridView1.DataSource as DataTable;

if (m_DataTable != null)
{
    DataView m_DataView = new DataView(m_DataTable);
    SortingExpression = e.SortExpression + " " + (SortingExpression.Contains("ASC") ? "DESC" : "ASC");
    m_DataView.Sort = SortingExpression;

    GridView1.DataSource = m_DataView;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}}
```

For some reason the "Gridview1.Datasource" came out as null. which where the reason for nothing to happen.
I ended up solving it like this:

```
       DataTable m_DataTable = new DataTable();

        string theMagicWord = Request["k"];

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Connection information"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "select mBank_file.Id, mBank_file.Filename, CONVERT(varchar, mBank_file.TimeUploaded, 105) AS Time from mBank_file INNER JOIN mBank_keywords ON mBank_file.Id = mBank_keywords.fileId WHERE mBank_keywords.Keyword = @key ";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@key", theMagicWord);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                var dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                m_DataTable.Load(dataReader);
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        if (m_DataTable != null)
    {
        DataView m_DataView = new DataView(m_DataTable);
        SortingExpression = e.SortExpression + " " + (SortingExpression.Contains("ASC") ? "DESC" : "ASC");
        m_DataView.Sort = SortingExpression;

        GridView1.DataSource = m_DataView;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

By retrieving the information from the database again, it worked like a charm.